# Using a for loop instead of if,elif?

Tags: python, object, compare

I can begin with what i've written:

```
for player in self.players:
    player.shot()

if self.players[0].best > self.players[1].best and  self.players[2].best:
    self.players[0].wins += 1
    print ("Winner: ", self.players[0].name, "\nResult: ", self.players[0].best)
elif self.players[1].best > self.players[0].best and  self.players[2].best:
    self.players[1].wins+=1
    print("Winner: ", self.players[1].name, "\nResult: ", self.players[1].best)
```

I know how to create a loop, but i dont know how to use it when comparing object values.
This only works if i know how many the players are so if there where 4 players, the code above would be useless. 
How do i write this in a loop that returns the highest of the self.best values?

Comment: I don't think your comparison does what you want it to. E.g. `self.players[0].best > self.players[1].best and self.players[2].best` is `(self.players[0].best > self.players[1].best) and self.players[2].best`; i.e. `self.players[2].best` is treated as `True` (nonzero) or `False` (zero).

Comment: I **think** this is how you meant it to be indented, but it's really hard to tell. Whitespace is important in Python. Please try to be consistent.

Comment: I know it's not correct but i thought since i was gonna change it anyway. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the player with highest `best`, you can use [`max()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#max) like this:

```
bestPlayer = max(self.players, key = lambda p: p.best)
bestPlayer.wins += 1
print ("Winner: ", bestPlayer.name, "\nResult: ", bestPlayer.best)
```

But this doesn't handle ties well. If more than two players have the same `best`, this will select one of them.

If you want to get all the players that have the highest `best`, you could use [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) and [`filter()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) like this:

```
best = max(map(lambda p: p.best, self.players))
bestPlayers = filter(lambda p: p.best == best, self.players)
```

Comment: This works great. I've actually used the lambda function for sorting the results, wasn't aware that you could use it like this. Still learning. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you think some answer actually answered your question, you should accept it by clicking on the green tick mark. You should also upvote any answers you think are good.

Answer (score 4):

The Pythonic way to do it is something like:

```
bestOfAll = max(p.best for p in self.players)
bestPlayers = [p for p in self.players if p.best == bestOfAll]

if len(bestPlayers) == 1:
    bestPlayer = bestPlayers[0]
    bestPlayer.wins += 1
    print ("Winner: ", bestPlayer.name, "\nResult: ", bestPlayer.best)
elif len(bestPlayers) > 1:
    # More than one player with best score. Resolve a tie?
```

The first line generates a list of the `best` properties of `self.players` and then finds the maximum. The next line generates a list of players whose scores match that best score. The rest of the program prints results. There really isn't any reason to mess with list indices.

Answer (score 0):

> I know how to create a loop, but i dont know how to use it when comparing object values.

The loop has nothing to do with the problem, and is not relevant to the task of comparing the objects.

> if self.players[0].best > self.players[1].best and  self.players[2].best

The logic is wrong here: this is not a natural-language AND, but a logical one. What you have described is: "Determine whether `self.players[1].best` and `self.players[2].best` are both true (nonzero), and then check if `self.players[0].best` is greater than that true/false value (1 for true, 0 for false)". To make both comparisons, you would have to repeat the comparison logic.

Fortunately, you don't need or want to do anything like that.

> How do i write this in a loop that returns the highest of the self.best values?

You don't.

You say "I want the highest of the self.best values", and then use the built-in Python function `max` (short for "maximum", another word for "highest" in context). The other answers explain how.

Comment: `a < b and c` equals `(a < b) and c`, not `a < (b and c)` as you say

Comment: Confound it. That represents something equally illogical, of course :)

Comment: @yak: operator precedence hardly matters here - the illogic of treating a numerical c (self.players[2].best) as a boolean is equivalent to the illogic of doing the numerical comparison `"a < boolean"`.  The OP's original statement, if read as an English sentence instead of Python code, clearly intended to group b and c before performing the comparison.

Comment: I realized that loop thing wasn't the problem right after i posted, but as you said, the others explained it well:)

Answer (score -1):

```
int playerno
int max = 0
foreach player in self.players
if(self.players[player].best > max)
{
playerno = player
max = self.players[player]
}
self.players[playerno].wins++
print ("Winner: ", self.players[playerno].name, "\nResult: ", self.players[playerno].best)
```

The syntax may be a little incorrect, but you should get the logic involved.